# Refresh userControl from outside class

Tags: c#, refresh

I have an application that displays result data from a database. Occasionally if a result comes in with additional data then we append the record. In the `UserControl` the values are "NA" until this happens. I have a `refreshdisplay()` method within the `UserControl` class that works beautifully, unfortunately if I call it from my `dataHandler` class after using `new` the `UserControl` does not refresh. I am guessing this is because I used

```
UserControlResultDisplay resultDisplay = new UserControlResultDisplay();
```

How can I use a method and interact with the existing UserControl without instantiating a new?

Here are some code snippets:

```
UserControlResultDisplay resultDisplay = new UserControlResultDisplay();

public void UpdateResultDB(ResultDataJFTOT resultData)
{    
    AnalysisListCommon myresult = PContext.GetInstance().DbHandlerLocal.StoredResult(
        resultData.SampleId,
        resultData.TestDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        resultData.InstrumentSn,
        StringRepository.constStringSampleName);
    if (myresult != null)
    {
        Result r = new Result(new Guid(myresult.ResultId));
        ResultData rd = r.GetResultData("Rating", FindResultDataMode.byVariableIdentifier);
        string xmlTubeRating = resultData.tRating.ToString().Replace("#LT#", "<");
        rd.Text = xmlRating;
        rd.Store();
        rd = r.GetResultData("TestDate", FindResultDataMode.byVariableIdentifier);
        rd.Text = resultData.Date.ToString();
        rd.Store();
        resultDisplay.RefreshDisplay();
    }
    else
    {
        AddTestToQueue(resultData);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Pass the existing reference in via the constructor? Thats how you normally do it... Am I missing something that prevents that?

Comment: I did that, but the use of keyword "new" seems to throw a hitch in my giddyup. Does this open a new instance of the UserControl instead of working with the open instance. The calling function is not in a form, therefore the function executes while the UserControl is open and visible. I am somewhat of a rookie so bear with me and elaborate if I am way off base.

Comment: If you pass it in as a parameter, you don't need the `new` keyword. Could you post the code where you do this?

Comment: @BradleyDotNet That is probably my issue then. Forgive me as I am still green. But I thought Objects in c# are not values and could not be passed. My apologies for asking something that I should know but... How do I do this

Comment: See my answer, hopefully it clears up your confusion a bit :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It did. I understand now how we can pass an object. I do however have a couple of questions I hope you can help me with. Should 'public MyDataClass(UserControlResultDisplay uidisplay)'be set to void (I know its a constructor but I am showing a no return error). I am still struggling with calling it from my class that updates the data. i.e. I need to instantiate UserControlResultDisplay to access MyDataClass.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55395/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-willkk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the problem lies in the statement:

```
UserControlResultDisplay resultDisplay = new UserControlResultDisplay();
```

This instantiates a new object (no relation to the existing one) so running functions on it has absolutely no chance of affecting what is displayed on the GUI.

Before I get to the correct code, let me try and clear up what an "Object" is.

Every type in C#, whether explicitly or implicitly, can be considered an "Object" (even value types like int), so that distinction is largely irrelevant. You are correct, however, in saying that there are two classifications of objects:

1. **Value Types** which are passed (not surprisingly) by value, and do not need/allow the `new` keyword during creation. These are your `int`, `float`, `char` etc.
2. **Reference Types** which are passed by *reference* and do use the `new` keyword to create them. These are anything declared with `class` (possibly a few others, but thats a good rule of thumb).

Both are perfectly acceptable parameters to any function, they are just passed differently. For what you are trying to do, we actually take advantage of this. If you write:

```
UserControlResultDisplay resultDisplay;

public MyDataClass(UserControlResultDisplay uiDisplay)
{
    resultDisplay = uiDisplay;
}
```

You are getting (and storing) a **reference** to the existing UI object. Now when you call functions on it, it will affect the UI (assuming everything on the UI side is set up correctly of course). You would invoke this constructor like this (assuming it is from the UI class):

```
MyDataClass data = new MyDataClass(this);
```

If you invoke it somewhere else, you obviously need a reference to the UI from somewhere else to pass to `MyDataClass`.